# SQL SELECT with conditional WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

**Abstract:**

I have a SELECT query with a WHERE condition which I **would like** to have met. In some cases this WHERE condition will not be met and in such cases I would like to use a different WHERE condition. That is the abstract problem I'm facing. Here is a more specific example:

**Example:**

I have a `tag` table and a `tag_l11n` table. The tag table contains basic information about a tag and the `tag_l11n` table contains the localized name of the tag. In the following simplified SELECT I'm requesting the tag with an English name (`tag_l11n_language = 'en'`)

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` as tag_id_3,
    `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_title` as tag_l11n_title_2
FROM 
    `tag` as tag_3 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_2 ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
WHERE 
    `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en' 
ORDER BY 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` ASC 
LIMIT 25;
```

**Problem:**

The problem starts if a tag doesn't have a certain translation. For example a tag may exist in English language but not in e.g. Italian language. However, the Italian guy would also accept the tags in English language (or any other language) **IFF** (if and only if) the Italian translation doesn't exist.

In the end I would prefer a solution where I could specify different priorities (1. localization of the user, 2. English, 3. any other language).

I'm a little bit at a loss here. While I could easily omit the condition (language = ??) and filter the result during the output/presentation, I don't think this is the way to go.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output in tabular form.

Comment: In other words - if the above query with the condition ``tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en'`` return no rows, then do another - almost the same query but with condition `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` <> 'en'``, is that correct ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @krokodilko correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a clause to your `WHERE` which will return a translation in English if the Italian translation didn't exist, using a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
WHERE 
    `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'it' 
OR
    `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM tag_l11n t3 
                    WHERE t3.tag_l11n_tag = tag_3.tag_id 
                      AND t3.tag_l11n_language = 'it')
```

Another (possibly more performant given it will not have an `OR` condition) solution would be to `LEFT JOIN` to `tag_l11n_2` twice, once for the desired language, and once for the backup, and using `COALESCE` to prioritise the desired languages result:

```
SELECT 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` as tag_id_3,
    COALESCE(`tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_title`, `tag_l11n_3`.`tag_l11n_title`) as tag_l11n_title_2
FROM 
    `tag` as tag_3 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_2 ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
                            AND `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'it' 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_3 ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_3`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
                            AND `tag_l11n_3`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en' 
ORDER BY 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` ASC 
LIMIT 25;
```

Note this can be expanded to as many backup languages as are desired by adding `LEFT JOIN`s and the appropriate columns to the `COALESCE`.

[Demo (of both queries) on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5b3c866a0fc624d79304adb9809c460f)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `or`ed join-conditions usually result in a bad plan. Additionally this logic is hard to extend if you want to add another language, e.g. this *any other language*

Comment: @dnoeth you raise a good point; I've edited the answer with an alternate query that would likely be more performant. Your approach using aggregation is also a good one.

Comment: @DennisEichhorn please note I've edited my answer with a query that may by more performant than the original. Also I've added a small demo of both queries.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I also modified a version where I could have any other language if none of the previous ones matched. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a5ce037b0ecd1e1258712810a05b34bd

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend `row_number()` to handle the prioritization:

```
SELECT tag_id_3, tag_l11n_title_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.`tag_id` as tag_id_3,
        tl.`tag_l11n_title` as tag_l11n_title_2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.`tag_id` ORDER BY
            (tl.`tag_l11n_language` = 'it') desc,
            (tl.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en') desc,
            tl.`tag_l11n_language`
        ) rn
    FROM `tag` as t
    LEFT JOIN `tag_l11n` as tl ON t.`tag_id` = tl.`tag_l11n_tag` 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY t.`tag_id`
LIMIT 25;
```

With this solution, you can manage as many levels of prioritization as wanted, by adding more conditions to the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()`. Currently this puts the Italian translation first, followed by the English translation, followed by any other available translation (alphabetically-wise).

Comment: Good to know, I don't have MySQL 8 but I will keep it in mind for the future since it seems really powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE-condition changes the LEFT to an INNER join, resulting in no row returned when there's no no row for `en`.

The classic solution utilizes one left join perm language and then COALESCE to get the first non-NULL value:

```
SELECT 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` as tag_id_3,
    coalesce(`tag_l11n_it`.`tag_l11n_title`  -- same order as join order
            ,`tag_l11n_en`.`tag_l11n_title`
            ,`tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_title`) as tag_l11n_title_2
FROM 
    `tag` as tag_3 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_it
ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_it`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
AND -- WHERE changes the LEFT join to INNER 
    `tag_l11n_it`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'it'  -- main language

LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_en 
ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_en`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
AND
    `tag_l11n_en`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'en'  -- 2nd language

LEFT JOIN 
    `tag_l11n` as tag_l11n_2
ON `tag_3`.`tag_id` = `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_tag` 
AND
    `tag_l11n_2`.`tag_l11n_language` = 'de'   -- default language
ORDER BY 
    `tag_3`.`tag_id` ASC 
LIMIT 25;
```

While GMB's solution works without default language, this solution requires a default (the language with no missing translation), in your case probably `de`:-)

Maybe GMB's query canbe improved by applying ROW_NUMBER *before* the join:

```
SELECT tag_id_3, tag_l11n_title_2
FROM `tag` as t
LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT 
        `tag_l11n_tag` as tag_id_3,
        `tag_l11n_title` as tag_l11n_title_2,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY t.`tag_id`
             ORDER BY
               CASE WHEN `tag_l11n_language` = 'it' THEN 1
                  WHEN `tag_l11n_language` = 'en' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
               END
            ,tl.`tag_l11n_language`) AS rn
    FROM `tag_l11n`
  ) AS t1
ON t.`tag_id` = tl.`tag_l11n_tag` 
WHERE t1.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.`tag_id`
LIMIT 25;
```

And this priorization logic logic can also be used with aggregation:

```
SELECT tag_id_3, tag_l11n_title_2
FROM `tag` as t
LEFT JOIN -- INNER JOIN should be possible
 (
    SELECT 
        `tag_l11n_tag` as tag_id_3,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN `tag_l11n_language` = 'it' THEN `tag_l11n_title` END)
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN `tag_l11n_language` = 'en' THEN `tag_l11n_title` END)
                ,MAX(CASE WHEN `tag_l11n_language` = 'de' THEN `tag_l11n_title` END)
                -- if there's no default you can get a random value using ,MAX(`tag_l11n_title`)
                ) AS tag_l11n_title_2
    FROM `tag_l11n`
    GROUP BY `tag_l11n_tag`
  ) AS t1
ON t.`tag_id` = tl.`tag_l11n_tag` 
ORDER BY t.`tag_id`
LIMIT 25; -- might be possible to move into Derived Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nick answer I came up with new idea to use function `FIELD()` which would cover all possible languages without joining separate table for each language but with one subselect. I am not sure about performance comparing to the other answers, but it would be faster if the languages are indexed by numerical values than strings (`en`,`it` etc.).

Of course translations with NULL should be excluded in subselect.

```
SELECT 
    `tag`.`tag_id` as tag_id,
    COALESCE(`tag_l11n`.`tag_l11n_title`,"No translation") as tag_l11n_title
FROM 
    `tag` as tag
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
          `tag_l11n_tag` as tag_id,
          `tag_l11n_title` as tag_l11n_title,
      FROM 
          `tag_l11n`
      WHERE 
          `tag_l11n_title` IS NOT NULL,
      ORDER BY
          FIELD(`tag_l11n_language`,"it","en","es")
      LIMIT 1
      ) as tag_l11n ON `tag_l11n`.`tag_id` = `tag`.`tag_id`
ORDER BY 
    `tag`.`tag_id` ASC
```

Comment: Apart from the typos, this will only give a result for the first value in the `tag` table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b9ae2d18277e34d79b22ae50cbe8227c